# Valgrind finds a leak in my code, could anybody help me find it?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have the following code for a function.
It reads a file, line per line, without knowing the size in advance.

It is a learning exercise in my school. I have run the valgrind command on it and I have this output (the full log is here => [valgrind log](https://gist.github.com/CamilleBC/b5d1493a7e2867309ae97f4a19827bfa)):

```
==21166== 44 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 14   of 42
==21166==    at 0x1000CB606: malloc (in /Users/cbaillat/.brew/Cellar/valgrind/3.13.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==21166==    by 0x100000F0C: ft_strnew (in ./get_next_line)
==21166==    by 0x10000061C: get_next_line (get_next_line.c:71)
==21166==    by 0x10000058A: main (main.c:31)
```

I don't know where that could come from. Here is the function that provokes the leak:

```
#include "get_next_line.h"

/*
** If newline is null, it means it hasn't found a new line in the string.
** It means we have reach the end of line.
*/

static int  ft_copy_leftover(char **line, char fd_buffer[BUFF_SIZE], char *nl)
{
    if (nl == NULL)
        return (1);
    ft_strcpy(fd_buffer, &nl[1]);
    (*line)[nl - (*line)] = '\0';
    return (1);
}

/*
** 1- We keep reading unless we find a new line or we reach the end of file
** 2- We reallocate the old pointer with buffer size
** 3- As long as there are characters to read and we haven't encountered a
**  new line, we keep copying the data into line
**  We store the buffer in line, and then erase it
** 4- If we have already reached the end of file, we do not need to copy the
**  buffer. Otherwise we copy it to line.
*/

static int  read_line(const int fd, char fd_buffer[BUFF_SIZE], char **line)
{
    int32_t     status;
    char        *newline;
    uint32_t    len;

    while (((newline = ft_strchr(*line, '\n')) == NULL)
        && ((status = read(fd, fd_buffer, BUFF_SIZE)) > FILE_READ))
    {
        len = ft_strlen(*line) + 1;
        if ((*line = ft_realloc(*line, len, len + BUFF_SIZE)) == NULL)
            return (ERROR);
        ft_strcat(*line, fd_buffer);
        ft_bzero(fd_buffer, BUFF_SIZE);
    }
    if ((**line != '\0') && (status >= FILE_READ))
        return (ft_copy_leftover(line, fd_buffer, newline));
    return (status);
}

/*
** 1- If the buffer is not empty, we allocate a new string and copy the buffer
**  contents
** 2- We loop in the buffer in case we have multiple new lines inside
*/

int         get_next_line(const int fd, char **line)
{
    static char fd_array[ULIMIT_N][BUFF_SIZE + 1];
    int8_t      status;

    if (fd < 0 || fd > ULIMIT_N || line == NULL
        || !(*line = ft_strnew(BUFF_SIZE + 1)))
        return (ERROR);
    if (fd_array[fd][0] != '\0')
        *line = ft_strcpy(*line, fd_array[fd]);
    ft_bzero(fd_array[fd], BUFF_SIZE + 1);
    status = read_line(fd, fd_array[fd], line);
    return (status);
}
```

The function 'ft_strnew' just mallocs memory for a string and memsets it to 0:

```
#include "libft.h"

char    *ft_strnew(size_t size)
{
    char    *str;

    if ((str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(*str) * (size + 1))) == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    ft_memset((void *)str, (int)'\0', (size + 1));
    return (str);
}
```

Could anybody help me find it?
By the way, this is how I call my function in the main:

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    int32_t i;
    int32_t fd;
    int32_t status;
    char    *line_read;

    if (ac <= 1)
        return (0);
    fd = open(av[1], O_RDONLY);
    i = 0;
    line_read = NULL;
    while (1)
    {
        status = get_next_line(fd, &line_read);
        // printf("status: %d\n", status);
        if (status == ERROR)
            return (ERROR);
        if (status == FILE_READ)
            return (SUCCESS);
        ft_putstr(line_read);
        free (line_read);
    }
    return (SUCCESS);
}
```

I free the malloc line (ft_strnew) everytime I call the function, so I am at a loss. If you need more information to help, I'd be glap to provide it. It is my first question on stack, I hope it is clear enough.

Thanks to all of you!

### **EDIT:**

I simply forgot to free the line in the while loop of my main, when returning some values. Adding a couple of free solved my problem! Thanks to all of you!

```
while (1)
    {
        status = get_next_line(fd, &line_read);
        // printf("status: %d\n", status);
        if (status == ERROR)
        {
            free (line_read);
            return (ERROR);
        }
        if (status == FILE_READ)
        {
            free (line_read);
            return (SUCCESS);
        }
        ft_putstr(line_read);
        free (line_read);
    }
```

Comment: `*line = ft_strcpy(*line, fd_array[fd]);` looks suspicious.

Comment: I don't modify the pointer, nor do I malloc anything in that function. My minor leak is probably because I don't free before some returns, but I'll only be able to check on Monday. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ft_strnew function you malloc a new string but you never free it.
I would suggest that you free line before returning status in your get_next_line function!

Comment: But I can't, this strnew is returned to the function that calls it (with a char **pointer). It is freed in the main function, in my loop.

Comment: On some cases, you are going to exit your main function without freeing the line_read first, try to free before returning!

Comment: Thanks, I did not notice that ! I'll try it on Monday !

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of possibilities. Firstly in your `while` loop, if you get certain values of `status` you exit without freeing `line_read`. That will only cause one block to be lost though.

Secondly, you overwrite the value of `*line` with this code

```
*line = ft_strcpy(*line, fd_array[fd])
```

which looks like the most likely candidate if you're allocating more memory in there. If you were changing it to a different point within that block, you'd get entirely different errors when you tried to free it.

Comment: Thank you Chris, that's probably it ! I don't have access to my gitrepo before Monday, but I'll test that and accept your answer  if it works! Cheers :)